# Создание необычного графика распредления

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Хочу построить необычный график, в котором от линии находится распределение. Не очень понимаю что именно надо делать.

Есть dataframe pandas:

```
date        time   Count    b_5 b_4 b_3 b_2 b_1 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5

20190911    195829  65658   217 33  15  17  11  5   25  14  28  28
20190911    195829  65658   217 33  14  17  14  5   25  14  28  31
20190911    195829  65658   217 33  14  17  14  5   25  14  28  31
20190911    195829  65658   217 33  61  47  14  11  14  28  31  80
20190911    195829  65659   213 61  49  17  8   17  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   13  122 59  17  11  14  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   23  119 59  17  12  14  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   23  119 59  17  12  14  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   23  119 59  14  12  14  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   23  119 59  14  12  14  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   23  119 59  14  12  14  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   23  119 59  14  12  14  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   23  119 59  14  12  14  31  28  80  13
20190911    195829  65659   23  119 59  14  12  14  31  28  80  13
```

Как видите есть график по Count - получается линия. А значения b и a это распредиление значений в стороны на одно значения Count     вверх (b) и вниз (a). Нарисовал в пейнте как это должно выглядить грубо говоря.
Но тут еще дело в том, что чем больше значение b или a, тем более например красного цвета она становится - тоесть от 0 до максимума раскаршивается от зеленого до красного (ну или какой цвет не столько важно). На примере внизу привел кстати небольшой кусочек, все таки в пейнет такое рисовать не очень. Думаю можно использовать точки для графика в виде matplotlib.pyplot.scatter, но может что то есть лучше. Значний b и a может быть побольше или поменьше чем 5/5, но всегда фиксированные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные у меня такие https://wdfiles.ru/ee87f6fd9cc233cc

Comment: дайте вопросу более осмысленный заголовок, пожалуйста.

Comment: То есть вы рисуете значения `count + b` и `count - a`? Либо я ничего не понял. Для закраски можно наверное использовать https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html

Comment: Переведите пожалуйста вот эту фразу "значения b и a это распредиление значений в стороны на одно значения Count вверх (b) и вниз (a)"  на русский язык. Во-первых и b и а  у вас несколько (по 5). Что означает каждое из них? Во-вторых,  распределение как правило показывает количество элементов по интервалам возможных значений. У вас для каждого момента (date        time )времени Сount -  одно.  Откуда взялось какое-бы то ни было "распределение"? И наконец, если "вверх (b) и вниз (a)", то по идее должно быть количество по середине. Где оно?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно я неправильно понял вашу задачу, поэтому не буду рисовать именно для ваших данных -  покажу принцип "на трех точках":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3]
y=[10,20,30]
c=[[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5],[-6,-4,-3,-3,-1,3,4,5,6,7],[-5,-5,-3,-1,-1,3,3,4,4,5]]
plt.scatter(x,y, c='red', s=75)

for i in range(len(x)):
    z=[y[i]+j for j in c[i]]
    clr=[abs(j) for j in c[i]]
    plt.scatter([x[i]]*len(z),z,c=clr)
```

Получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немного комментария. Три точки. Для каждой есть базовое значение (y) и есть отклонения от нее - массив с. Чем дальше от "базы" ставиться точка -  тем "желтее" становиться ее цвет. Надеюсь "подогнать" ответ именно под вашу задачу - затруднений не составит: и цвета подобрать, и правильно пересчитать значения каждой точки исходя из семантики ваших данных. Ну и распространить на весь ваш массив
P.S. Вместо первого скаттер-графика  можно построить plot-график.

Comment: Если "чем больше значение, тем краснее", то там еще проще - цвет строиться не по массиву C, а по массиву Z.  Если у вас исходные данные ДатаФрейм, то во-первых,    в каждой строке "мой" массив C - это ваши значения b и а, а мой массив Y -  это ваш столбец Count. А "мой" внешний цикл превращается в цикл по самому ДатаФрейму.

Comment: Если хотите строить свою шкалу, используя крайние значения (их-то найти легко -  min и мах c с этим справятся), то надо использовать  библиотеку matplotlib, модуль colors, объект LinearSegmentedColormap.  Он как раз и строит нужную вам расскраску.

Comment: Вам надо не "это" переводить в Датафрейм, а Датафрейм  переводить в "это" -  т.е. преоразовывать каждую строку к списку, и далее по приведенной схеме (скрипту).